Why is the Spring Boot new version like this? The old version doesn't.Annotation-specified bean name 'application' for bean class [xxx.Application]
Why is the Spring Boot new version like this? The old version doesn't.Annotation-specified bean name 'application' for bean class [xxx.Application]
This is a multi-module demo.
Annotation-specified bean name 'application' for bean class [calculation.Application] conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [customer.Application]
The Customer's module depends on the calculation module, so set to scan all xxx packages
package xxx.coupon.customer;
@SpringBootApplication()
@EnableJpaAuditing
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"xxx"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"xxx"})
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"xxx"})
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}

package xxx.coupon.calculation;
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}

They are all named Application, but the old version 2.4.2 (jdk11) of Spring-Boot-Starter-Parent allows this configuration. However, the new version 3.2.4 (jdk21) does not support it.
error:
2024-04-07T20:20:49.365+08:00  INFO 38288 --- [coupon-customer-serv] [           main] cn.noobbb.coupon.customer.Application    : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-04-07T20:20:49.557+08:00  WARN 38288 --- [coupon-customer-serv] [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [cn.noobbb.coupon.customer.Application]
2024-04-07T20:20:49.804+08:00 ERROR 38288 --- [coupon-customer-serv] [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [cn.noobbb.coupon.customer.Application]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:179) ~[spring-context-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:416) ~[spring-context-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:289) ~[spring-context-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:349) ~[spring-context-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:118) ~[spring-context-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:788) ~[spring-context-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606) ~[spring-context-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1354) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at cn.noobbb.coupon.customer.Application.main(Application.java:28) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.context.annotation.ConflictingBeanDefinitionException: Annotation-specified bean name 'application' for bean class [cn.noobbb.coupon.calculation.Application] conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [cn.noobbb.coupon.customer.Application]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.checkCandidate(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:361) ~[spring-context-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:288) ~[spring-context-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanAnnotationParser.parse(ComponentScanAnnotationParser.java:128) ~[spring-context-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:306) ~[spring-context-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:246) ~[spring-context-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:197) ~[spring-context-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:165) ~[spring-context-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    ... 13 common frames omitted


I want to know where to cause these differences
And, if the names of each Application are changed to different names, there will be multiple modules at the same time @Enablejpaaudition.

You cannot have multiple beans with the same name, the name has to be unique. Earlier versions worked around this by numbering the beans if detected, or silently overriding them. Leading to all sorts of intersting problems, hence the uniqueness has been enforced instead of trying to work around it. So fix your names of the classes. Your concern is invalid as all configurations will be merged.
